# table data has lot of space at the bottom in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to decrease the bottom on a table row. But it's not decreasing away. I have huge fonts, the only way to clear the space below is to decrease the font sizes but that again does create equally proportionate space below. I have tried defining the height in the `<tr>` and `<td>` (inline), but they don't respond to smaller size only bigger than what it is now. Here's my code :

```
<tr>        
 <td colspan="3" class="style1" height="250px">            
     <p id="two"> 2 </p> 
     <p id="zero"> 0 </p> 
     <p id="one"> 1 </p> 
     <p id="six"> 6 </p>
     <p id="wishes"> Best wishes </p>
     <p id="sender"> From Steve </p>         
 </td>
```

This is a table head

```
<table style="padding: 2em;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#455a64" width="100%"></table>
```

Fonts are bold `150px` and gradually smaller.
At this point I am thinking about converting it to image in photoshop and put it in the html.

This how my problem looks like

[image]

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/milan_light/505Lougg/

Comment: No don't use an image, that's bad practice and also bad for SEO! Could you post the complete table and not just the tr tag please? Have you tried setting the height, margin and padding on the p tags?

Comment: We can't imagine from image post full code and if possible create fiddle.

Comment: Here's JS fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/milan_light/505Lougg/

Comment: It's the relative positioning that's causing the blank space.

Answer (score 0):

first,I think you maybe can use 'padding' and 'margin' to replace your table's 'cellpadding' and 'cellspacing',and you can reset the css,then set your table css.
It's a good way,not affected by the style of it;

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with the margin removed from the p tags and using span tags for the numbers so they don't break onto new lines.

HTML:

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="style1">
        <span id="two"> 2 </span>
        <span id="zero"> 0 </span>
        <span id="one"> 1 </span> 
        <span id="six"> 6 </span>
        <p id="wishes"> Best wishes </p>
        <p id="sender"> From Steve </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.style1 {
  padding: 2em;
  background: #455a64;
}

#wishes, #sender {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

And here it is on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mikhailjan/qcvsthrm/2/